# r-studio: "warning in install.packages: installation of package "spant" had non-zero exit status" problem

Tags: r

running R (version 4.2.2) and R Studio (version 1.4.1717), with 10GB of memory. trying to install the toolbox "spant" on HPC (high performance computer) cluster, and i get this error

`> Warning in install.packages: installation of package "spant" had non-zero exit status` 
what am i missing to fix this? i tried using devtools too, and it didnt work

this is the entire command window:

```
install.packages("spant")
Installing package into ?/home/traaffneu/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2?

# (as ?lib? is unspecified)

also installing the dependencies ?testthat?, ?nloptr?

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/testthat_3.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 739497 bytes (722 KB)

# ==================================================

downloaded 722 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nloptr_2.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2219877 bytes (2.1 MB)

# ==================================================

downloaded 2.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/spant_2.16.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4908377 bytes (4.7 MB)

# ==================================================

downloaded 4.7 MB

ERROR: failed to lock directory ?/home/traaffneu/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2? for modifying
Try removing ?/home/traaffneu/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-testthat?
Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ?testthat? had non-zero exit status\*
ERROR: dependency ?testthat? is not available for package ?nloptr?
removing ?/home/traaffneu/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/nloptr?\*
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ?nloptr? had non-zero exit status\*
ERROR: dependency ?nloptr? is not available for package ?spant?
removing ?/home/traaffneu/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/spant?\*
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ?spant? had non-zero exit status\*
The downloaded source packages are in

# ?/scratch/myname/50755618.dccn-l029.dccn.nl/Rtmpyt6poN/downloaded_packages?\*

Warning message:
R graphics engine version 15 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

i have the most recent version of R Studio available for the HPC... ive tried many times, and i dont have access to the sudo so i cant install it that way. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: this doesnt solve your problem but you could install an older version of r that is compatible with the rstudio you are running, or maybe you dont need the graphics engine anyway

Comment: Follow the advice, close RStudio and on a command window remove file `/home/traaffneu/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-testthat`. Then restart RStudio and try to install the package.

Comment: BTW, while the warning message at the end has nothing to do with the inability to install packages, it is a clear problem that needs to be resolved for you to have "normal" functionality as you learn R. Download a more-recent version of the RStudio IDE (or, not-recommended, but you can try to downgrade R itself, though that's less appealing).